# How to write IIS rewrite url rules for blocking pages under a certain foldername?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

In IIS url rewrite module, I want to write a rule that blocks any request that tries to access a file under these folders, and make it case insensitive.

```
/Messages
```

or

```
/Templates
```

I have so far

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Fail bad requests">
      <match url="^/Messages/.*"/>
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
      <action type="AbortRequest" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="SPA Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <!-- match everything by default -->
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <!-- unless its a file -->
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <!-- or a directory -->
        <!--<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />-->
        <!-- or is under the /api directory -->
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
        <!-- list other routes or route prefixes here if you need to handle them server side -->
      </conditions>
      <!-- rewrite it to /index.html -->
      <action type="Rewrite" url="App/index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

but it does not work. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Read FRT and see what it says.

Comment: what is FRT? any link?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Besides, could you please tell me which url you have tested doesn't work? The rule you have used will not match the case insensitive and the "/Messages" url.